# Any chances of fixing a broken mainboard?

Tags: motherboard, thinkpad, laptop-repair

I've got here a Thinkpad T60 which has, according to phone support, a broken motherboard.

Is there any chance that I can fix this? (I fear not…)

When I press the power button it lights up all the control lights (1 sec) and shuts down immediately afterwards. I can't see anything on the display.

*Edit:* Sometimes when I try to start it multiple times in a row it starts to beep.

**Update 1**: Today I copied the files from the hard disk. For this I took the hard disk out and put it into an external case. I then put the hard disk from the external one into the laptop and surprisingly it booted the bootloader. When I'm at home I'll try to start it from a CD.

**Update 2**: I reinstalled the original hard disk and now it works, strange...

**Update 3**: The computer crashes sometimes. Especially when starting windows. It has successful passed a memtest, but it crashes after some time testing the hard disk for bad blocks.

Comment: Just to check, did you remove the battery, the CD-ROM drive, and the hard drive from the computer and try powering it up?  I've seen a bad battery and CD-ROM cause the same problem.

Comment: Maybe even remove the Mini-PCI wireless card, too, just to be sure.

Comment: @hyperslug: I'll try that.

Comment: @gs, didn't work, eh?  Sorry to hear.

Comment: Strangly I've got _some_ success. (See updated question.)

Comment: @gs, do you have any spare laptop HD's to test with?

Comment: No, unfortunately I haven't got a SATA hd. I'm pretty sure it must be the disk controller as the disk itself seems to be fine (S.M.A.R.T and using an external case). As long as I don't access the disk the system works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Update 3: The computer crashes
>   sometimes. Especially when starting
>   windows. It has successful passed a
>   memtest, but it crashes after some
>   time testing the hard disk for bad
>   blocks.

First, I'd recommend downloading the [ultimate boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) - it has a broad variety of diagnostics that could come in handy.

There is definitely a hardware problem, hence the knee-jerk "mainboard" diagnosis.  As has been suggested, your best bet is to strip the system down as much as possible and test.  Then add back one component at a time to see where it starts to fall down.

From what you've said so far, it sounds like either a problem with the HD controller (integrated in the mainboard) or a RAM problem.  You might want to run a RAM test overnight to see if it turns up any problems.

Comment: And don't add the battery back until you're sure the computer is working; if you had said it was desktop, one of my guesses would have been a bad PSU.

Answer (score 3):

while it is not entirely impossible to fix a 'broken' mainboard (provided you have appropriate diagnostic and soldering tools and replacement parts), it is much easier to replace the entire mainboard.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely no. You'll need to have it replaced. If it shuts down, it's probably shot.

If the computer turns on, shows lights, *stays on*, but hangs, I'd say it could be fixed by resetting the bios/cmos. But shutting down immediately doesn't sound good. We'll need more info to possibly help.

Answer (score 1):

I hope your unit is still under warranty, but from what you write it doesn't sound like it.  Replacement motherboards [seem to run](http://www.google.com/products?q=thinkpad+t60+motherboard&aq=f) $300 and up, less for a "refurb".  If you try a refurb mainboard, you might be able to get credit by sending the guy who fixes them your old one to work on.

The good news is, replacing the motherboard in a ThinkPad is usually really easy.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends what the problem is - there is no harm in opening it up and re soldering parts if you find anything obvious such as a burnt out capacitor... but it won't be easy.

You may be better off ringing a replacement / spare parts company and finding a replacement motherboard or even just getting a different second hand laptop off of eBay.